# Linear Transformation from $C[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ (integration)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider $L(f)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x) dx$ for all $ f∈C[a,b]$
>
> $L$ maps $C[a,b] \to \mathbb{R^1}$

Why does performing integration on a function output something that is in  $\mathbb{R^1}$?

If that was not worded correctly, please correct me. I can clarify as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a definite integral. It maps the function to the signed area under $y = f(x)$, between $x = a$ and $x = b$, which is a real number.

Comment: Ah, right! Is it impossible to assign a vector space if it were an indefinite integral?

Comment: Actually, I think it is possible, but I've never seen anyone do it for any reason. You wouldn't map to functions; you would map to equivalence classes of functions, deemed equivalent if they differed by a constant function. You can also map $$f \mapsto \left(x\mapsto\int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)$$if you want to map to a specific antiderivative (which one often depends on the choice of $a$).